# MVC routing to Index if no action found in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a multi-page form in my application, and as such, each method posts to the next. This works fine unless you try to visit the URL of one the methods decorated with `[HttpPost]`.

Is there any way I can route all 404 requests within this specific controller to the `Index` method?

Comment: have a look on MVC routing catchall {*url}, you might check this article http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/09/three-common-aspnet-mvc-url-routing-issues/

Answer (score 1):

I will post this as an answer because I am not able to add it as comment

have a look to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386347/asp-net-mvc-controller-handleunknownaction-404-or-405), it might help you

The idea you can catch the error in the `OnActionExecuting` and there you can make redirect

also as mentioned in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812235) in the answer, you can handle the `Controller.OnException`

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Bail if we can't do anything; app will crash.
        if (filterContext == null)
            return;
            // since we're handling this, log to elmah

        var ex = filterContext.Exception ?? new Exception("No further information exists.");
        LogException(ex);

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        var data = new ErrorPresentation
            {
                ErrorMessage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.Message),
                TheException = ex,
                ShowMessage = !(filterContext.Exception == null),
                ShowLink = false
            };
        filterContext.Result = View("Index", data); // to redirect to the index page
    }
}
```

after this you can let all your controller to inhert from `BaseController`

Comment: Oh I see!! Helpful :)

Comment: @jumpingcode I updated the answer by adding another possible way to solve it

Comment: I'm not sure it would raise an exception because it is simply 404

Comment: @jumpingcode ok, then kindly check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895 especially the long answer that signed by community wiki, hope it will help you